# How to correctly style prism regions from modules

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

My question is a rather high level concept question, so if you need more information please let me know.

I'm learning Prism, with modules and regions using WPF and MVVM.  If we take a very basic example where I have `ModuleAViewOne`, and `ModuleBViewOne`, and I want to inject them both into a main `Shell`, my concern lies with styles.  I see a major advantage in using Prism and modules in the fact that ModuleA and ModuleB could potentially be developed by different teams of developers.  Saying that, there's the possibility of them looking **completely** different (style-wise) and when they're injected into the main Shell it would look weird.

So my first thought is providing general styles inside the shell that controls how these Modules look.  This works great until the ModuleView itself has ***styles of its own***.  Then those styles DO NOT get overridden by the main Shell.

What is the best practice (if there is one), in creating a shell, and the modules in such a way that the shell has complete control in deciding how the modules look.  Also I'm assuming that is the desired behavior.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your common styles in `Shell` or `App.xaml`. In your module views, in their style declaration, use the `BasedOn` property to ensure that a lot of the style is inherited.

For example in `App.xaml`

```
<Style x:Key="BrightTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Then in your module views, define their styles like so:

```
<Style x:Key="MyModuleViewTextBlock" 
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BrightTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17" />
</Style>
```

This will then get a green foreground and a fontsize of 17.

The modules should have the most control over their style, as the styles have smaller scope. If you wish shell to define the styles completely, the module views should not be defining their own styles.

Comment: Great answer! I am curious about the `BasedOn` attribute.  If that resource does not exist, does the module throw a runtime error? Or simply set the fontsize to 17?

Comment: If the resource being targetted by `BasedOn` does not exist I believe it throws a runtime error. If you wish to have some form of conditional style inheritance, take a look [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=384) for an example of how to write custom markup.

Comment: I'm having a problem getting this to work. My module view is in a User Control Library project. It displays in design view fine but when I run the application is says 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception - cannot find resource